# Resetting byte[] buffer to zeros?

Tags: java, sockets, buffer

In the following code for sockets, I declare a byte buffer and listen for client messages in a loop:

```
// Create some buffer
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

while (true)
{
    // Listen for messages from Client

    int length = socket.getInputStream().read(buffer);

    if (length != -1)
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
    else
        break;

    // Reset buffer here to zeros?
}
```

Each time I'd require to reset the contents of buffer to receive a new message. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: That's not a reliable way to receive a string over a socket. There's no guarantee a complete encoded byte array will be returned in a single `read()` call. Use `DataInput/DataOutput` `readUTF()/writeUTF()` or something equally reliable.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: or I could pass length of message in bytes..

Comment: Yes, that could work, especially if you use the methods of `DataInput/DataOutput` such as `readInt()/writeInt()` and `readFully()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to reset the buffer, you need to a `String` constructor that does not go past the end of the part of the buffer that has the bytes received:

```
if (length != -1) {
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, length));
}
```

Now your code will work even if the buffer is dirty.

**Note:** For better portability pass the desired `Charset` to `String` constructor. Otherwise the `String` you construct may not match the string that has been transmitted to you through the socket.

Answer (score 21):

Agree with [dasblinkenlight answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456037/4391450), but to answer the question itself (how to reset an array), you can use [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(byte[],%20byte)) to set a value to every cell

```
byte[] array = new byte[10];
Arrays.fill(array, (byte)0);
```